# How to Create Cloudflare Origin CA certificate via API without providing private key and CSR

Tags: cloudflare, terraform-provider-cloudflare

Via the Cloudflare UI (see image), it's possible to create an Origin CA certificate without providing a private key and CSR. Cloudflare will generate this for you.

I've tried to find the corresponding approach using the Cloudflare API, but it seems I have to provide a self generated key and CSR when doing that.

Does anyone know if it should be possible to auto generate via the API (or Terraform/Pulumi) as well?

https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/origin-ca-create-certificate#requests

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found the answer to my question in the Pulumi provider documentation. They are creating a key and certificate signing request before using them when calling cloudflare.

https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/cloudflare/api-docs/origincacertificate/

```py
# Create a CSR and generate a CA certificate
example_private_key = tls.PrivateKey("examplePrivateKey", algorithm="RSA")
example_cert_request = tls.CertRequest("exampleCertRequest",
    key_algorithm=example_private_key.algorithm,
    private_key_pem=example_private_key.private_key_pem,
    subjects=[tls.CertRequestSubjectArgs(
        common_name="",
        organization="Terraform Test",
    )])
example_origin_ca_certificate = cloudflare.OriginCaCertificate("exampleOriginCaCertificate",
    csr=example_cert_request.cert_request_pem,
    hostnames=["example.com"],
    request_type="origin-rsa",
    requested_validity=7)
```